# C#: Best Practices Debug.Print

Tags: c#, unit-testing, debugging, trace

What is the best practice regarding [`Debug.Print`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.aspx) statements?

Should I litter my class methods with `Debug.Print` statements or should I avoid `Debug.Print` altogether?

If `Debug.Print` statements are acceptable should I consider using [`Trace.Print`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or [`EventLog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)?

Are `Debug.Print` statements necessary with unit tests? Can I avoid `Debug.Print` statements with well written unit tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Debug.Print` is acceptable, not least because they'll be compiled out in your release builds. "Littering" your code with it, however, doesn't sound especially productive or useful.

You can add it while debugging a particular area of code. Once you identify the defect, you can write a unit test to cover the case, fix the bug, and then remove the call to `Debug.Print`.

What I sometimes use and leave in the code base is `Debug.Assert` -- it is like a built-in breakpoint if my application is not in an expected state, which is just an added safety net while doing both automated and manual testing.

`Debug.Print` is not necessary in unit tests, and should not be added for the sake of unit tests.

Comment: Note that `Debug.Assert` statements are also [removed in a Release build](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13383661/1497596). (Unless `DEBUG` has been added to the Release configuration.) Consider using [`Trace.Assert`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6752696/1497596) instead if you want your assertions to execute in a Release build.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Debug.Print at all with unit tests! The point of unit tests is that you automatically get an indication whether the test succeeded or failed, you don't need to look for debug prints for that.

[NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/) is an easy-to-use unit testing library.

As for tracing or logging, you don't need to litter your code with debug prints for that either. Try [interception with Castle Windsor](http://stw.castleproject.org/Windsor.Introduction-to-AOP-With-Castle.ashx?HL=intercept) or other frameworks that support AOP.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Debug.Print or Trace.Print.  I do write a good amount of unit tests.  I've never found that I need to use the Debug or Trace objects with the unit tests that I write.  I do try to unit test as much as possible, however.