# Is there a version of Debug.Assert() that will check the condition on release?

Tags: c#, .net

I need a version of Debug.Assert() that, in a release build, will still execute the code in the condition parameter but will not show an assertion dialog if the assertion fails. Is there such a tool in .NET 3.5 or will I have to implement this myself (if I even can)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Trace.Assert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.assert.aspx) for this, it works in release mode as well.  See the documentation on how to use listeners to use another method than making a dialog come up.  An excerpt:

The display of the message box depends on the presence of the DefaultTraceListener. If the DefaultTraceListener is not in the Listeners collection, the message box is not displayed. The DefaultTraceListener can be removed by the <clear> Element for <listeners> for <trace>, the <remove> Element for <listeners> for <trace>, or by calling the Clear method on the Listeners property (System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Clear()).

So for example:

```
#if (!DEBUG)
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Clear();
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. What exactly is the XML they are referring to? Is that the Visual Studio Project XML? Somehow the application needs to know when to register the DefaultTraceListener for debug but not release.

Comment: The XML is in your app.config file. You can define tracing and debugging options there.  However, you can simply define a clear in release mode.  I'll edit my answer to show that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply execute the code and check the result with Debug.Assert?

```
bool isOk = CodeToBeExecuted();
Debug.Assert(isOk == true);
```

Comment: This would require him to recode all his asserts, rather than a quick search and replace of Debug.Assert with Trace.Assert.  Also, the asserts will no longer tell him what's wrong, they'll all just be "isOK failed".

Comment: Not only that but in release I will have an unreferenced variable (I'm not sure if this will result in a compiler warning, I know in C++ it would).